# Recursive view that sum value from double tree structure SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion

First sorry for numerous repost of my question, I'm new around and getting used to properly and clearly asking questions.

I'm working on a recursive view that sum up values from a double tree structure.

I have researched around and found many questions about recursive sums but none of their solutions seemed to work for my issue specifically.

As of now I have issues aggregating the values in the right cells, the logic being i need the sum of each element per year in it's parent and also the sum of all the years for a given element.

Here is a fiddle of my tables and actual script:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a6bce2/26)

And here is a screenshot of the output I'm looking for:

[image]

**My question is:**
How can I get my view to aggregate the value from child to parent in this double tree structure?

Comment: Why did you delete the previous version of the exact same question?

Comment: My bad, as stated I'm new around and still unused to how things are done on stack overflow. I reformulated my question slightly and felt it was more appropriate to ask a new than keep what was seen as a poorly formulated question.

Comment: Well done posting sample data and such. But it is not clear what you want as ouput. I see the image but what is the logic you are trying to capture?

Comment: EntityOne and Two tables are tree structure tables joined together by a middle table containing both Values and Year. I need to aggregate the values in a view that sum these values from child to parent based on Year distinctly and as total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to get an aggregation at 2 different levels to show in a single result set.

**Clarification Scenario:**

Below is an over-simplified sample data set for what I believe you are trying to achieve.

```
create table #agg_table
    (
        group_one int
        , group_two int
        , group_val int
    )

insert into #agg_table
values (1, 1, 6)
    , (1, 1, 7)
    , (1, 2, 8)
    , (1, 2, 9)
    , (2, 3, 10)
    , (2, 3, 11)
    , (2, 4, 12)
    , (2, 4, 13)
```

Given the sample data above, you want want to see the following output:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| group_one | group_two | group_val |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|         1 | NULL      |        30 |
|         1 | 1         |        13 |
|         1 | 2         |        17 |
|         2 | NULL      |        46 |
|         2 | 3         |        21 |
|         2 | 4         |        25 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

This output can be achieved by making use of the [`group by grouping sets`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx)
 (example G. in the link) syntax in SQL Server as shown in the query below:

```
select a.group_one
, a.group_two
, sum(a.group_val) as group_val
from #agg_table as a
group by grouping sets
    (
        (
            a.group_one
            , a.group_two
        )
        ,
        (
            a.group_one
        )
    )
order by a.group_one
, a.group_two
```

What that means for your scenario, is that I believe your Recursive-CTE is not the issue. The only thing that needs to change is in the final select query from the entire CTE.

**Answer:**

```
with Temp (EntityOneId, EntityOneParentId, EntityTwoId, EntityTwoParentId, Year, Value)
as
(
    SELECT E1.Id, E1.ParentId, E2.Id, E2.ParentId, VY.Year, VY.Value 
    FROM ValueYear AS VY
    FULL OUTER JOIN EntityOne AS E1
    ON VY.EntityOneId = E1.Id
    FULL OUTER JOIN EntityTwo AS E2
    ON VY.EntityTwoId = E2.Id
),
T (EntityOneId, EntityOneParentId, EntityTwoId, EntityTwoParentId, Year, Value, Levels)
as
(
    Select 
        T1.EntityOneId,
        T1.EntityOneParentId,
        T1.EntityTwoId,
        T1.EntityTwoParentId,
        T1.Year,
        T1.Value,
        0 as Levels
    From
        Temp
            As T1
    Where
        T1.EntityOneParentId is null
    union all
    Select
        T1.EntityOneId,
        T1.EntityOneParentId,
        T1.EntityTwoId,
        T1.EntityTwoParentId,
        T1.Year,
        T1.Value,
        T.Levels +1
    From
        Temp 
            AS T1
    join
        T
            On T.EntityOneId = T1.EntityOneParentId
)
Select 
    T.EntityOneId,
    T.EntityOneParentId,
    T.EntityTwoId,
    T.EntityTwoParentId,
    T.Year,
    sum(T.Value) as Value
from T
group by grouping sets
  (
    (
      T.EntityOneId,
      T.EntityOneParentId,
      T.EntityTwoId,
      T.EntityTwoParentId,
      T.Year
    )
    ,
    (
      T.EntityOneId,
      T.EntityOneParentId,
      T.EntityTwoId,
      T.EntityTwoParentId
    )
  )
order by T.EntityOneID
, T.EntityOneParentID
, T.EntityTwoID
, T.EntityTwoParentID
, T.Year
```

FYI - I believe the sample data did not have the records necessary to match the expected output completely, but the last 20 records in the SQL Fiddle match the expected output perfectly.

Comment: It works partially, but it work. The values do aggregate in the first layer of data the way expected. It's having issues with the root not getting any values at all, could this be related to the way i make my select at first? In any case, thanks for your answer! It got me a step closer to a completely working view.

Comment: @Cpt.TeaBag Do you mind elaborating on the issue via an update in the question? Might be able to take a look after you add to the question.

Comment: I made a question related to this topic at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48158873/recursive-query-in-2-tree-structure-at-once-in-sql-server. You might wanna check there. Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: Just a heads up, I found the issue with my top values. it was indeed in my initial select. Replaced it with a function to generate my table and then applied your solution for the math, it works wonder!